# Merge columns with same header containing split data

Tags: excel, merge, vba

I have an Excel-file where row 2 contains headers. Some of these headers are "cloned" and data are divided between the two clones (in linked file below for example Column Q and T and AK and AQ). In column Q there are some empty cells and T contains data to be put in these empty cells.

See following file for an example:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18908464/Example.xlsx

I've been looking for a code to search row 2 for columns with same header and then merge these into one column with no empty cells and if possible delete the empty column after merging.

Using Excel 2013.

Comment: Do you have more than 2 of these to do? If not, I'd just do it by hand. That's going the be the most efficient . Or is this something you do on a semi-regular basis?

Comment: This is something that is going to be done on a semi-regular basis so I'm looking at automating it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will merge all columns with duplicate headers

- It brings data from a duplicate column (T) into first column to its left (Q) if the cells in Q are empty

Paste it in a standard VBA module then add a reference in VBA:

- Navigate to Tools > References
- Scroll down and select **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**
- Click anywhere inside the code and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run it (on a copy of the file)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub mergeColumns()
   Const HDR As Long = 7      'header row
   Const HDC As Long = 2      '(first) header column

   Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, lCol As Long, hRow As Variant, i As Long
   Dim ac As New Dictionary, dc As New Dictionary, c1 As Variant, c2 As Variant
   Dim itm As Variant, dCols As Range, d As Range, tr As String
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1")
   lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, HDC).End(xlUp).Row
   lCol = ws.Cells(HDR, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   If lRow > HDR And lCol > HDC Then
      hRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(HDR, HDC), ws.Cells(HDR, lCol)).Value2
      For i = 1 To lCol - HDC + 1 'find dupes ---------------------------------------------
         tr = Trim(hRow(1, i))
         If Len(tr) > 0 Then
            If ac.Exists(tr) Then dc.Add ac(tr), i + HDC - 1 Else ac.Add tr, i + HDC - 1
         End If
      Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      For Each itm In dc 'merge columns ---------------------------------------------------
         c1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(HDR, itm), ws.Cells(lRow, itm)).Value2
         c2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(HDR, dc(itm)), ws.Cells(lRow, dc(itm))).Value2
         For i = 1 To lRow - HDR + 1
            If Len(Trim(c1(i, 1))) = 0 Then c1(i, 1) = c2(i, 1) 'trimms blanks
         Next
         ws.Range(ws.Cells(HDR, itm), ws.Cells(lRow, itm)).Value2 = c1
      Next
      For Each itm In dc 'delete duplicate columns ----------------------------------------
         Set d = ws.Cells(HDR, dc(itm))
         If dCols Is Nothing Then Set dCols = d Else Set dCols = Union(dCols, d)
      Next
      If Not dCols Is Nothing Then dCols.EntireColumn.Delete
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End If
End Sub
```

---

Tested with about 1 million records (Total rows: 994,503 in: 3.9453125 seconds)

---

[image: before and after]

**Edit:**

- I made one adjustment to work with fields that seem to be blank but actually contain spaces
- Some "blank" your new file contain 7 spaces (which translates to 7 characters, so not blank)

  - Example: Cells H54, 55, 56, etc

I included a Trim() function that removes all white spaces (tabs, carriage returns, etc)

Other than that I adjusted:

- `Const HDR As Long =`**7**
- `Const HDC As Long =`**2**

and

- `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`("**Ark1**")

The new file before and after:

[image: before and after 2]

Comment: Thanks Paul. This worked like a charm! Had to do some minor edits as I'm running it from a different file as part of an "edit and import" process.

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad it helped. The 3 main adjustments are for `HDR` (header row), `HDC` (first data column) and `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Krysstabell")` to use whatever sheets you have to run it on

Comment: Hey @paulbica and thanks again for the help on this one. I have a similar case to the one you solved above and was wondering if it is possible to make changes in the above code to make it work on the file i've uploaded here: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rkl7b60lyg3otm/test.xls?dl=0
Note that there is duplicate numbers for "tørrstoff (E)" in the duplocate columns where the second number in the second column can be deleted.

Comment: I tested (and adjusted it a bit) for the new file; see may edits for details

Comment: Cheers @paulbica I've teste it and it works with the file i uploaded, but I see you've set header row to 7 when it should be 6 as this is the header. The duplicate columns are named "11, 0-3-1m Jord" and "11, 0-3-1m. Jord". Where the duplicate contains a "." in it and the first number 83,7 (in this case) in the duplicate column is a duplicate as well. Is it possible to edit your code to make it work so header row is 6, where it searches for duplicate headers containing "." and first number (if there) in duplicate column should be deleted, and columns merged and empty deleted as before. Sense?

Comment: Hi Morten, the code works for what Excel considers duplicates; for example if you create a Conditional Formatting rule for row 6 (ELEMENT) to highlight duplicates Excel will not find any. Even if the difference is 1 character, you need custom logic for it: the code will need to check each character in each header and compare the sequence to all other headers to determine if the pattern "digit-letter-dot" is found; if it is then find the header with all other character the same except for the dot. But then you need to exclude cases where the dot appears in a different position of the sequence

Comment: Cheers @Paulbica that's a whole new question by the sound of it. Is it feasible you think or too much coding for too little gain? Manual labor is the option and not a bad one but my dream is to make it happen without the need of human touch :)

Comment: If the only difference you will ever have is "1m" vs "1m." you can have a separate implementation just for this exception, but it's still custom logic different than duplicates. But if you will find other exceptions you'll need to have different code for each one. And yes, for this particular question we should probably leave the current answer as the accepted, as it is more generic (you can open a new question for the special case)